# getting this error "Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile" on Azure DevOps pipeline build

Tags: java, maven, azure-devops

I have a maven project which is running successfully on my local machine eclipse. But when I ran the same on Azure DevOps pipeline it says "Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile"

I have tried all the possible configurations in my pom. I am almost to give up on this.

UTF-8

```
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>

</properties>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Suite testng xml file to consider for test execution -->
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
                <forkMode>never</forkMode>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\javac.exe</executable> 

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: Can you share your pipeline?

Comment: really sorry to disappoint you but it is not my private pipeline hence can not share.

Comment: So how we can help you? maybe you have an issue in the pipeline configuration?

Comment: I think then I need to replicate this same stuff on the other new pipeline to share with you. how do we share by the pipeline way?

Comment: I just changed my agent from ubunto to windows. it solved. Thanks @Shyaki .

Comment: @Yuvraj, It seems you have resolved your question, would you mind share your solution as answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and find the answer easier. Thanks.

Comment: @Leo Liu-MSFT . I already have, please read the comment just above yours.

Comment: @Yuvraj, Yes, I have seen it. But that is a comment, would you please convert it to the answer, so so it could help other community members who get the same issues and find the answer more easier, thanks. like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58028887/import-repository-from-github-to-azure-repos

Answer (score 0):

I just changed my agent from ubunto to windows. it solved.