# Import Repository from Github to Azure Repos

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

If I import a repository from Github to Azure repos using the import functionality in Azure Devops. Will it bring across all branches as they are on the server? Ow will i need to import each branch one at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it Does, it brings all branches across as is. I did a test

Answer (score 1):

The default import functionality in Azure DevOps will import the entire repository, including all branches. so you'll only have to do a single import to get all the history in there